# Numbers not adding correctly in function

Tags: python

For instance, if I input the numbers '5', '5', '3', and '4' I get '5534'.  I want to get '17'  Can somebody explain to me what's wrong?

```
def grade_lab(lab_number, student_id):
    student = student_id
    lab_count = lab_number
    step1 = '1'
    gradeforstep1 = problem_solving(step1)
    step2 = '2'
    gradeforstep2 = problem_solving(step2)
    step3 = '3'
    gradeforstep3 = problem_solving(step3)
    step4 = '4'
    gradeforstep4 = problem_solving(step4)
    scoregrade = gradeforstep1 + gradeforstep2 + gradeforstep3 + gradeforstep4
    points_earned = f"Student: {student} earned {scoregrade} points on lab {lab_count}."
    return points_earned

def problem_solving(step_graded):
    stepgrade=input(f'Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step {step_graded}:')
    finalstepgrade = stepgrade
    return finalstepgrade

def main():
    labgrade = grade_lab(3, 12345)
    print (labgrade)
    step = input()
    gradeforstep = problem_solving(step)
    print(gradeforstep)
main()
```

Comment: You are getting the numbers as string. Convert them to integer with int()

Comment: "Adding" strings concatenates them. If you want to get integer input, you need to cast it using `int()`

Comment: Where do I put int() ?

Comment: `return int(finalstepgrade)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert numbers to integers before you add them. For example:

```
scoregrade = int(gradeforstep1) + int(gradeforstep2) + int(gradeforstep3) + int(gradeforstep4)
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you could wrap the inputs with `int()`:

```
stepgrade=int(input(f'Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step {step_graded}:'))
```

**FULL CODE**

```
def grade_lab(lab_number, student_id):
    student = student_id
    lab_count = lab_number
    step1 = '1'
    gradeforstep1 = problem_solving(step1)
    step2 = '2'
    gradeforstep2 = problem_solving(step2)
    step3 = '3'
    gradeforstep3 = problem_solving(step3)
    step4 = '4'
    gradeforstep4 = problem_solving(step4)
    scoregrade = gradeforstep1 + gradeforstep2 + gradeforstep3 + gradeforstep4
    points_earned = f"Student: {student} earned {scoregrade} points on lab {lab_count}."
    return points_earned

def problem_solving(step_graded):
    stepgrade=int(input(f'Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step {step_graded}:'))
    finalstepgrade = stepgrade
    return finalstepgrade

def main():
    labgrade = grade_lab(3, 12345)
    print (labgrade)
    step = input()
    gradeforstep = problem_solving(step)
    print(gradeforstep)
main()
```

Comment: When I do that I get:
'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Make sure it is all typed correctly, I have just run it and it seems to work...

Comment: Can you show me your code?

Comment: I've just added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a misunderstanding of variable types and recasting.

Perhaps peruse some free resources like these class notes and make sure you understand these concepts: [Python 101: Input and Casting](https://github.com/branhoff/python_class_101/blob/main/01-lesson_notebooks/02d-Input_and_Casting.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

Input returns an string, convert it to integer to make numeric operations. As you have a messy code, I cleaned it in my solution:

```
def grade_lab(lab_number, student_id):
    scoregrade = 0
    for i in range(1,5):
        scoregrade += int(input(f'Please enter a score 0 - 5 earned for understanding step {i}:'))

    return f"Student: {student_id} earned {scoregrade} points on lab {lab_number}."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(grade_lab(3,12345))
```